# How to update the existing dbcontext in asp.net core 1.1

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have used below command to create the dbcontext

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Data Source=SANPC;Initial Catalog=EMAKITI;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Data
```

The above command successfully created the dbcontext with all table.

Now, I have change some column of table and used the below command to update

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Data Source=SANPC;Initial Catalog=EMAKITI;Integrated Security=True;Trusted_Connection=True;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Entity -context EmakitiContext -Project DataBase -force
```

The above command gives me a error

> The specified deps.json [D:\GitAlpha\eMikitiWebApi\eMikitiWebApiPortal\src\eMikitiWebApiPortal\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.1\eMikitiWebApiPortal.deps.json] does not exist
>   Process finished with non-zero exit code

I have done lots of research. Not able to solve this issue.I am using asp.net core 1.1

here is the project.json file

```
    {
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Design": "1.1.0",
    "DataBase": "1.0.0-*",
    "UnitOfWork": "1.0.0-*",
    "ViewModel": "1.0.0-*",
    "Common": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.1.2",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet": "1.0.0-preview3-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: try to delete existing files and then create again. make sure create backup before deleting.

Comment: no it didn't help .... same problem... I, have update to .net core from 1.0 to 1.1 and now I, am facing this issue

Answer (score 0):

You are using code first approach and in this approach changes flow from code to database. Entity Frame work give us option to start from existing database with reverse engineering. When we did once reverse engineering to generate our models, after that we need to follow the migrations flow in code first approach code to database.

With this command we generatee migrations

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate -c SchoolContext
```

and with this we apply it to database.

```
dotnet ef database update -c SchoolContext
```

You can learn more about this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/migrations)

Comment: I am not using the code first approach. The problem is with when I updated asp.net core 1.0 to asp.net core 1.1. When I was using 1.0 the same command was working now the command is not working